# text does not display correctly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please loot at my HTML and tell me why it's not working correctly and what I can do to resolve it. The issue is that text inside the span is not displaying correctly. What I don't understand is that ><12(a number) displays correctly.

Here's the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rwfg0wtL/

Here's the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=0 style='table-layout:fixed;display:block; width:100%; cellPadding=3;' class='previewText'>

        <thead>
            <colgroup>
                <col align='left' width='20px'>
                <col align='left'>

            </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr id='complaintrow' name='complaintrow' selected=true>
                <td style="" width:20px"" valign="" top""><img src='images/checkon.gif' height=16 width=16 style='cursor:hand' language=vbscript onclick='select'></td>
                <td align=left>
                    <span language=vbscript ondrop='StopBubble' onpaste='CheckPaste' class=labelOnPreviewcc style="" width:100%; word-break:break-all;"" id=txtValue>

                         ><test <!--'This does not work-->
                        <br/>
                         ><12 <!--this works--> 
                        <br/>
                        ><1test <!--this works-->
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `&lt` and `&gt` instead

Comment: You need to use HTML Entities to escape it: `&lt;` for every `<` and `&gt;` for every `>`. Furthermore `&amp;` for every `&`. Otherwise you’ll have invalid HTML.

Comment: You also need to fix your span-tag `language='vbscript' ondrop='StopBubble' onpaste='CheckPaste' class='labelOnPreviewcc' style='width:100%; word-break:break-all;' id='txtValue'`

Comment: You should fix all the quotes in your HTML then  get back to us.

Comment: `<1` “works” because tags can’t start with numbers. `<test` does and is highly invalid.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Don’t forget the `;`s.

Comment: Thanks guys.. It's some legacy code that I cannot change..I was just getting confused as to why <Number was displaying but <Letter was not.

Comment: @Xufox Good catch, I always forget those. Too late to edit comment though :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<`, `>` and `&` are not allowed in raw text in XML or in HTML. To put them in a document, you need to type `&lt;` (less than), `&gt;` (greater than) and `&amp;` (ampersand).